# Using onerror on an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, onerror

The following snippet will replace the PNG image with GIF image if the link is broken or does not exist. I tried to apply this on an iframe but it does not seems to work. Is this even possible?

```html
<html>

 <body>

 <iframe src="index1.html" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='https://media.giphy.com/media/3oEjI6SIIHBdRxXI40/giphy.gif';"> </iframe>
 <img src="test.png" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='https://media.giphy.com/media/3oEjI6SIIHBdRxXI40/giphy.gif';" />

 </body>

</html>
```

Would greatly appreciate response. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You can use JS separately to check if t a link exists display id_a else display id_b

Comment: Hi Muhammed, I have a bit of an idea in my mind that javascript can do this but i am not really sure how I can execute it

Comment: I wonder if you could do a `no-cors` fetch and just catch errors.

Answer (score 7):

> The onerror event is triggered if an error occurs while loading an external file (e.g. a document or an image).

The iframe content is not a file, thus, onerror won't be triggered. You can use JS to check if you get an HTTP success response (200).

```js
var myRequest = new Request('index1.html');

fetch(myRequest).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response.status); // returns 200
}).catch(function(error) {
  document.getElementById("iframe-id").src = "/your/file/path/here/somePage.html";
});
```

```html
<iframe id="iframe-id" src="index1.html"> </iframe>
<img src="test.png" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='https://media.giphy.com/media/3oEjI6SIIHBdRxXI40/giphy.gif';" />
```

Comment: Thanks itay but how can I make the page redirect if the link does not exist in an iframe?

Comment: Did you try it? the specific url obviously won't work, you need to replace it with your real existing url

Comment: Yes, I tried it locally, and it appears that it keeps loading the src that was stated on this line: document.getElementById("iframe-id").src = "/your/file/path/here/somePage.html"; even if the url exists in the same folder.

Comment: "_locally_" is not HTTP, but FILE instead. Look at the URL of the browser: if it starts with `http` you can do [XHR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest), but if it starts with `file` you can't. The answer here only works online (speak: when being served via HTTP).