# How to show alternative text if Iframe can't load the resource at src in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a running Angular 12 application and I am implementing a behavior where I need to fetch the content from external site and display inside the modal popup. I am using `<iframe src="url">` to fetch the content from separate application. If the website server is on, I am able to fetch the content and display inside the modal.

But, if the server is down, its showing:

```
localhost connection refused
```

I want to implement a behavior where if the server is down; show the legend "**Server is down**" in the modal instead of localhost connection refused.

**display-content.component.ts**

```js
contentUrl: string;
serverDown: string;

constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  const url= "http://localhost:5000/getContents"; 
  this.contentUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
}

onIframeError(event) {
 console.log('iframe failed');
}
```

**display-content.component.html**

```html
<iframe [src]="contentUrl " frameborder="0" class="content" (load)="onIframeError($event)"></iframe>
<p *ngIf="serverDown">Server is down</p>
```

Comment: `iframe`s should have an error handler. You could just listen for errors with it, and then toggle `serverDown`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, iframe doesn't have any error handler. It just has one load event which gets called on both iframe load and fail

Comment: You're also responsible for the content page that's being loaded? If so you could implement a communication path using `postMessage()`. If you don't receive a new message in *t* ms after the frame did load, you can consider it's not your page that's been loaded. Alternatively, if you really just wish to see if the server is down (as opposed to a simple 404 or other error response), you can do `fetch(frame.src, { mode: "no-cors", method: "HEAD" })
  .then((resp) => /* Server is up */ )
  .catch((err) => /* Server is unreachable */);`

Comment: [This is a possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52639526/using-onerror-on-an-iframe)

Comment: @kaiido Thanks, I tried using fetch and able to get the error if server is down. But, if the server is up and I am trying to print resp.status, the value is coming as 0 instead of 200. any idea why this is happening...?

Comment: Using `mode: "no-cors"` the response is opaque. All you'll know from it is if the browser was able to get a response at all, from which we can derive that the server is up. However you won't be able to read the status of that response, that would leak information on cross-origin resources, which we don't want. If you need to handle that too, then you have a bigger problem, unless if you can set up said server to accept AJAX requests made from yours, in which case you wouldn't need the `mode: "no-cors"`.

Comment: But if you can set up that server this way, you can probably even set it up to allow same-origin access from the iframe directly and just check from its `contentWindow` if the page loaded was the expected one.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this :

display-content.component.ts

```
contentUrl: string;
serverDown: boolean | undefined;

constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer, private _http: HttpClient) {
    const url= "http://localhost:5000/getContents"; 
    this.contentUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);

    this._http.get(url, { observe: 'response' })
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(resp => {
         if (resp.status === 200 ) {
           this.serverDown = false;
         } else {
           this.serverDown = true;
         }
       }, err => this.serverDown = true);
     }
```

display-content.component.html

```
<iframe *ngIf="serverDown === false" [src]="contentUrl " frameborder="0" class="content"></iframe>
<img src="loadingImage" *ngIf="serverDown === undefined"/>
<p *ngIf="serverDown">Server is down</p>
```

Comment: this._http.get(url) is not able to hit the url, maybe because of CORS.

Comment: More details? @AsifZaidi

Comment: They said the iframe is from an "external site", i.e cross-origin.

Comment: @FlorianRADUREAU my application is running on localhost:5010 and I am hitting localhost:5010 to get content and display inside iframe. <iframe src="http://localhost:5000/getContents">. So when I am trying http.get(), its not able to subscribe and hence the resp.status === 200 or else part is not getting executed